# Android : Is their a MODE that let me read my data in internal storage

Tags: android, ddms, android-internal-storage

my question is pretty basic but I can't find the answer here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html
. Is it possible to make a file like that :

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(file,MODE_PRIVATE);
                fOut.write(data.getBytes());
                fOut.close();
```

but changing the MODE_PRIVATE by something like MODE_WORLD_READABLE (depreciated since API 17 and now when I use it it goes in the catch automaticly)?
I know how to access the data (DDMS - File Explorer - /data) but I can't create a file which I have access to !

PS: for those who want to know I'm try to make a directory with directories and files inside and I want to see if what I'm doind is right or not

**SOLUTION**

It's impossible to see your internal storage data with DDMS (impossible maybe not but I didn't succeed). You must go to **C:\Users\UserYouWant\AppData\Android\sdk\platform-tools** => make a cmd => write **adb root** => write **adb shell** => cd **data/data/your project package/files** and there are all your files.

Comment: If you want users to have independent access to the file, use what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). [Internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) is for the private use by your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't users to have access to it, when I finish my app I will go back to MODE_PRIVATE. For now I just want to use internal storage like normal but have access to the data. Is there no "mode for devellopers" that allow you to see what you're actualy doing ?

Comment: "Is there no "mode for devellopers" that allow you to see what you're actualy doing ?" -- correct. There are recipes for using `adb shell run-as` to copy files from your internal storage to external storage, that you can then download. Also, on an emulator, you might be able to use DDMS to browse `/data`, or use `adb shell` to browse `/data`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Damn... Hate when android make things harder for dev ! I'm trying to access data with **adb root** and **adb shell**, will edit my question if it works. And I tried with DDMS to browse the data repository but it stays empty...

Comment: @CommonsWare I succeed and edited my solution ! Thanks for the hints !